# How I can use where Condition in SQL I have comma separated value in A columns in multiple rows

Tags: sql

```
Column1    EventTypes_pKey
Are      5,3
Test     1,4,5
test     1,3,5
```

If I am using
Select * from Table name where EventTypes_pKey in('5,1,4)
then I want that record where these value belongs the column.

How I can use where condition on the basis of EventTypes_pKey this is my Varchar column.
I want If I am selecting 5,3,4 the there should be all three row data.
Please help me.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store multiple values in a single column!  Do not store numbers in strings!  Properly declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: The _correct_ solution to your problem is to rework your data model, and create a properly normalized one-to-many relationship

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, you can do this by by converting the value into an array and then using the [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator `&&`

```
select *
from badly_designed_table
where string_to_array(eventtypes_pkey, ',')::int[] && array[5,3,4];
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c774576e67abbf08b205fb5c767076e2)

Comment: Not understand with your answer

Comment: @RahulKumar: well, it answers your question: return all rows that contain one of the provided values.